# Best way to store variable

Tags: php

I need to save the value of a variable to use on another page. What is the best way to do this?

$ _SESSION is not a possibility because it will be executed by cronjob.

apc_store seemed to me an excellent function for this but it does not seem to work anymore or needs to install extension on server to work.

Is there any native PHP alternative?

Edit:
I use Curl to get the value in a site1 and saved in a variable then it is redirected to Site2 where I want to retrieve the value of that variable. Using POST is not possible because it is a form and would conflict the data that the form needs with the data I am passing. The application does not use DB, creating one so this would be bad.

Cookies falls into the same SESSION problem (I'm using cronjob)

I think the best solution would be a txt file manipulated by file_put_contents.
Would that be the only solution?

Comment: how about a file of db

Comment: You can use a database or a file, what data do you need to save and how do you want to use it might change the answer.

Comment: cookie or send this value with `post`

Comment: Did you look [here](http://php.net/manual/intro.apc.php)? Note the section marked _"Alternatives to this extension"_

Comment: This question is confusing- do you have control over both the server side code _and_ the client-side code (which I presume is where your cron job is?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> apc_store seemed to me an excellent function for this but it does not seem to work anymore or needs to install extension on server to work.

The APC variable cache is not suitable for this application -- it isn't shared between the web server and CLI scripts, and values stored in the cache may be evicted at any time.

If you need a value to be reliably stored across executions of a CLI script, write it to a file or store it in a database.